# How to find which column is having untranslatable string in Teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am new to Teradata and I was querying to one table, but I am getting result as **SELECT Failed 6706 The string contains an untranslatable character.**

I don't know which column is having untranslatable character.

Can anyone help me how to find the untranslatable character and remove that.

Comment: Can you write your query here please?

Comment: It is just a basic query select * from table_name

Comment: then start with basic [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/teradata-select-statement)

Comment: i am asking how to remove not tutorial

Comment: Remove one by one column in the query and find the column that has created a problem

Comment: Also: Is your session character set defaulted to ASCII (i.e. Teradata LATIN)? Try specifying UTF8 in your connection string - exact syntax depends on the API / driver in use.